# Enforce nocookie mode when using the YouTube iframe API

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I'd like to ensure that when I initialise a `new YT.player()` that I can set it to make sure that it uses an embed from the `www.youtube-nocookie.com` domain. Is this currently possible? I haven't been able to find any reference to it in the docs yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know, this is a late answer, but maybe relevant as it's still working:

You can use the host-parameter:

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'aqz-KE-bpKQ',
    host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
    playerVars: {
      origin: window.location.host
    }
  });
}

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```

Sadly, it does not work here on stackoverflow because of the same-origin-policy.

I have the same code running in an active project, though..

Comment: The host parameter works, the iframe src shows https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/, but the video still displays ads. Tried it on a few videos and they display ads. When I use https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/ with iframe embed (not Iframe API), videos don't display ads. Any ideas why it shows ads with the Iframe API?

Comment: host parameter works, but it is not (yet) documented at https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I managed to solve this just as I was about to post my question.

In my code I use something like:

```html
<iframe id="myVideo" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/<VIDEO_ID>?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

...then I can use the following to get the player that has already been embedded in the HTML via JS:

```
var player;
var onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
  player = new YT.Player("myVideo");
};
```

Still, it would be nice if there was a way to initialise a `www.youtube-nocookie.com` video with JS too.

Comment: Does your setup display ads on embedded videos? When I use youtube-nocookie.com with iframe embed (not Iframe API), videos don't display ads. But when I use it with Iframe API, videos display ads. Any ideas why it shows ads with the Iframe API? Listenonrepeat.com seems to be doing it, but couldn't figure out how they do it...